# Dificuldade com Ajax Jsonp

Tags: ajax, api, jsonp

Estou tentando consumir uma api através do Ajax , porém obtenho erro ao executá-lo.

```
var data2 = {
    resource_id: '1d7e45e5-b159-46a2-bdce-90393c7a8a2b', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    q: 'jones', // query for 'jones'      
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_search',
    data: data2,       
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data2)
    {
        debugger;
        alert('Total results found: ' + data2.result.total)
    }
});
```

No Console do navegador observei que ele adiciona dois parametros que não passei :`callback=jQuery21409543886738626624_1528899809074 e &_=1528899809075`

URL que aparece no console:

```
https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_search?callback=jQuery21409543886738626624_1528899809074&resource_id=1d7e45e5-b159-46a2-bdce-90393c7a8a2b&limit=5&q=jones&_=1528899809075
```

Como deveria ser:

```
https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=1d7e45e5-b159-46a2-bdce-90393c7a8a2b&limit=5&q=jones
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu Ajax inclua o `cache: true` veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458731/4312593) o porquê

> No Console do navegador observei que ele adiciona dois parametros que não passei :callback=jQuery21409543886738626624_1528899809074 e &_=1528899809075

```js
var data2 = {
  resource_id: '1d7e45e5-b159-46a2-bdce-90393c7a8a2b', 
  limit: 5,
  q: 'jones',    
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_search',
  data: data2,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  cache: true,
  success: function(result) {
    alert('Resultados encontrados: ' + result.result.total)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema . Muito grato !

Comment: Eu que agradeço. Se possível vote como resposta. Att.